# Boundary conditions for the time-independent Schrödinger equation on the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

if you have a free Schrödinger operator on a sphere 
$-\Delta \psi(\theta,\phi) = E\psi(\theta,\phi),$ then the substitution $\psi(\theta,\phi) = f(\theta)e^{i n \phi}$ leaves you with the differential equation

$$- f''(\theta)- \cot(\theta) f'(\theta) + \frac{n^2}{\sin^2(\theta)} f(\theta)+ = E f(\theta).$$

For $n=0$ this simplifies to 
$$- f''(\theta)- \cot(\theta) f'(\theta)= E f(\theta).$$

My question is: What are the correct boundary conditions for the ODE after the substitution?

Comment: What do you know about $V$, especially its behavior near the endpoints of $[0,\pi]$?

Comment: After your edit, the answer you received looks nonsense. You should at least restore the reference to $V$ IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Calculus distance scale factors in spherical coordinates are $s_{r}=1$, $s_{\theta}=r$, $s_{\phi}=r\sin\theta$. So the Laplacian is
$$
     \Delta=\frac{1}{s_{r}s_{\theta}s_{\phi}}\left[
  \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{s_{\theta}s_{\phi}}{s_{r}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
  +\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\frac{s_{r}s_{\phi}}{s_{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\frac{s_{r}s_{\theta}}{s_{\phi}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\right]\\
%%   = \frac{1}{r^{2}\sin\theta}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r^{2}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
%%   + \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
%%   + \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\right]\\
   = \frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+
     \frac{1}{r^{2}\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\frac{1}{r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\phi^{2}}.
$$
The following restriction to the sphere is the correct Laplacian on the sphere:
$$
       \Delta_{S}=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\theta}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\phi^{2}}.
$$
The natural $L^{2}_{S}$ inner-product is
$$
        (f,g)_{S} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta,\phi)\overline{g(\theta,\phi)}\sin\theta\,d\phi d\theta.
$$
And, as you noted, if $\psi(\theta,\phi)=\Theta(\theta)e^{in\phi}$, then
$$
            \{-\Delta+V(\theta)\}\psi = e^{in\phi}\left[-\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}-\frac{n^{2}}{\sin^{2}\theta}+V(\theta)\right]\Theta(\theta).
$$
The function $\phi(\theta,\phi)=e^{in\phi}\Theta(\theta)$ is in $L^{2}_{S}$ iff $\Theta \in L^{2}_{\sin}[0,\pi]$, which is to say
$$
         \|\Theta\|_{\sin}^{2}=\int_{0}^{\pi}|\Theta(\theta)|^{2}\sin\theta\,d\theta < \infty.
$$
It is not enough to require that $\psi \in L^{2}_{S}$ in order to study this problem in a classical manner. For example, suppose $V=0$ and suppose $n=0$; then
$$
                     \Delta \Theta(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}\Theta.
$$
Therefore $\Delta\theta(\theta)=0$ iff
$$
              \Theta(\theta) = A+B\ln\left(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}\right).
$$
Note: All such solutions are in $L^{2}_{S}$, but you don't want the solution where $A=0$, $B=1$ being part of a classical solution. The presence of the logarithmic solution is an artifact of the vanishing Jacobian $\sin\theta$ of the coordinate transformation; this vanishing allows the fundamental solution of $\Delta F=\delta_{n}-\delta_{s}$ to creep into things, where $\delta_{n}$ is the Dirac delta at the North pole and $\delta_{s}$ is the Dirac delta at the South pole.

So why is it not a good idea to allow the logarithmic solution into your formulation of the problem? Physicists sometimes argue that it makes no sense to allow an unbounded pure state in the system. There's a compelling case to made for this, but it's not entirely satisfying to invoke such a condition when there is a clear Mathematical necessity to disallow this type of state based on the axioms of Quantum Mechanics: If you define $\Delta$ on the domain consisting of $C^{2}$ functions on the manifold, and you add the logarithmic function to the domain, then the resulting operator is no longer symmetric! And that leads to an unacceptable Hamiltonian for Physics. Indeed, there are $C^{2}$ functions $\psi$ on $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ such that
$$
   \left(\Delta\ln\left(\frac{1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\right),\psi\right)_{S}=0
    \ne \left(\ln\left(\frac{1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\right),\Delta\psi\right)_{S}.
$$
That is reason enough to exclude the logarithmic function from any domain of a Hamilton which includes $C^{2}$ functions on the manifold: Quantum Hamiltonians are selfadjoint and, hence, also symmetric. The exclusion of this function is equivalent to the requirement that pure states be bounded, which justifies the Physicist's reasoning.

A standard way to arrive at a selfadjoint operator $\Delta_{S}$ is to start with functions that are $C^{2}$ on the sphere as a manifold, and then show that $\Delta$ is symmetric and has a sefladjoint closure $\Delta_{S}$; that's one way to overcome the artifact of a vanishing Jacobian. And it leads to an alternative characterization of the domain of $\Delta_{S}$ as consisting of functions in a Sobelev space. This is because the first order derivatives remain in $L^{2}_{S}$ under this closure operation because of the identity
$$
\begin{align}
               (-\Delta f,f)_{S} & = \int_{S}|\nabla f|^{2}\,dS \\
    & = \int_{S}\left( \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right|^{2}
      +\left|\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\right|^{2}\right)\,dS < \infty.
\end{align}
$$
And this condition excludes the fundamental logarithmic solution because
$$
   \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln\left(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}\right)=\frac{1}{\sin\theta} \notin L^{2}_{S}.
$$
The resulting operator is unique inasmuch as it is the closure from a natural manifold domain which is invariant under all symmetries of $\mathbb{S}^{2}$. This one gradient condition is then propogated to the individual eigenfunction equations:
$$
            \int_{0}^{\pi}\left(|\Theta_{n,m}'(\theta)|^{2}+\frac{n^{2}}{\sin^{2}\theta}|\Theta_{n,m}(\theta)|^{2}\right)\sin\theta\,d\theta < \infty.
$$
This last condition is met for all of the classical Associated Legendre Polynomial solutions $\Theta_{n,m}$, in addition to the requirements that $\Theta_{n,m}$ be in $L^{2}_{\sin}[0,\pi]$.

**Added:** Back to your case. If $V$ is smooth in $\theta$, then you can view the addition of a potential as a bounded perturbation with $\|V\|\le \sup|V|$. This is a general fact: If $A$ is a bounded on unbounded selfadjoint operator and $V$ is a bounded selfadjoint operator then $A+V$ is selfadjoint on $\mathcal{D}(A)$. So I'm not going to worry about $V$ in the discussion. Without knowing more about your specific $V$--which has not been answered--I was prepared to deal with forms in order to handle the more general perturbation.

As a final note, I'll be more explicit about the separation of variables connection. You can write every $f \in L^{2}_{S}$ as $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f_{n}(\theta)e^{in\phi}$, and $\|f\|^{2}_{S}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{2}_{\sin}[0,\pi]}^{2}$ follows.

To put this back on the ODEs, let $-\Delta_{0}$ be the restriction of $-\Delta$ to the $C^{\infty}$ functions which vanish in a neighborhood of the North and South poles. If $f$ is $\mathcal{D}(-\Delta_{0})$, then $f=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{in\phi}f_{n}(\theta)$, where $f_{n}$ is $C_{c}^{\infty}(0,\pi)$. For any such $f \in \mathcal{D}(-\Delta_{0})$,
$$
    -\Delta_{0} f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{in\phi}L_{n}f_{n},\\
     L_{n}f_{n}=\left[-\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}+\frac{n^{2}}{\sin^{2}\theta}\right]f_{n},
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
    (-\Delta_{0} f,f)_{S} & = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}
       (L_{n}f_{n},f_{n})_{\sin} \\
     & = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \|f_{n}'\|_{\sin}^{2}+\|\frac{n}{\sin\theta}f_{n}\|^{2}_{\phi}.
\end{align}
$$
The Friedrichs extension $-\Delta_{f}$ of $-\Delta_{0}$ is the restriction of $(-\Delta_{0})^{\star}$ to the domain of functions $f$ for which the above form is finite. The Friedrichs extension $-\Delta_{f}$ is automatically selfadjoint and semibounded.

The nice thing about the Friedrichs extension is that the conditions for it can be put off onto the ordinary differential operators (ODOs) through the individual quadratic forms, which is evident from the sum representation for $(-\Delta_{0}f,f)_{S}$. This gives us something substantial because the adjoint of an ODO is well known and classical, whereas the domain for the PDO is not so easy to study in general. For example, the Friedrichs extension of $L_{n}$ has a domain consisting of all twice locally absolutely continuous functions $f$ for which $f, L_{n}f, f', \frac{n}{\sin}f$ are in $L^{2}_{\sin}$. On this domain integration by parts is allowed, and the conditions can be translated to endpoint conditions. For example, suppose $n\ne 0$. Then
$$
    f_{n}, \frac{1}{\sin\theta}f_{n}', -\frac{1}{\sin\theta}(\sin\theta f_{n}')'+\frac{n}{\sin^{2}\theta}f_{n} \in L^{2}_{\sin}.
$$
So all of these, and the products of any two of these are in $L^{1}_{\sin}[0,\pi]$. That gives you a lot of things to look at, and they all result in a limiting expressing for an integral with respect to the upper limit. For example, the following has finite limits as $\theta$ approaches either endpoint:
$$
    f_{n}(\theta)-f_{n}(\pi/2)=\int_{\pi/2}^{\theta}\frac{1}{\sin\theta'}f_{n}'(\theta')\,\sin\theta'\,d\theta'
$$
A condition more directly related to the form is
$$
    \int_{\pi/2}^{\theta} \overline{f_{n}}L_{n}f_{n}\,d\theta'
      = \int_{\pi/2}^{\theta}\left( -\overline{f_{n}(\theta')}(\sin\theta'f_{n}'(\theta'))'+\frac{n}{\sin\theta'}|f_{n}|^{2}\right)d\theta' \\
    = \left.-\sin\theta' \overline{f_{n}}f_{n}'\right|_{\pi/2}^{\theta}
      + \int_{\pi/2}^{\theta}\sin\theta'|f_{n}'|^{2}+\frac{n}{\sin\theta}|f_{n}|^{2}\,d\theta'
$$
From this last condition you can conclude that the evaluation term has a limit as $\theta$ approaches either endpoint. Similarly, the following also has endpoint limits:
$$
                  \sin\theta \frac{d}{d\theta}|f_{n}|^{2}.
$$
And, the endpoint limits are $0$. Otherwise there is a non-zero $C$ such that
$$
                  \frac{d}{d\theta}|f_{n}|^{2} \approx \frac{C}{\sin\theta},
$$
which will contradict the fact that $|f_{n}|^{2}$ has a finite limit at each endpoint. I'll let you continue the analysis to match Teschl's.

**Discrete spectrum of $L_{n}+V$:** The spectrum of $L_{n}$ is discrete with eigenvalues $\lambda_{n,m}$ that tend to $\infty$. If $\lambda\notin\sigma(L_{n})$, then $(L_{n}-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is compact because it has a complete orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions with eigenvalues $\frac{1}{\lambda_{n,m}-\lambda}$, a sequence which tends to $0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$. The resolvent of $L_{n}+V$ is equal to the following for all $\lambda$ for which $\|V(L_{n}-\lambda I)^{-1}\|< 1$:
$$
\begin{align}
    (L_{n}+V-\lambda I)^{-1} & =\left[(L_{n}-\lambda I)(I+(L_{n}-\lambda I)^{-1}V)\right]^{-1} \\
   & = (I+(L_{n}-\lambda I)V)^{-1}(L_{n}-\lambda I)^{-1}
\end{align}
$$
In particular, because $\|(L_{n}-\lambda I)^{-1}\|\le 1/|\Im\lambda|$, then the above holds at least for $\|V\|_{\infty} < |\Im\lambda|$. That's enough to conclude that some resolvent operator $(L_{n}+V-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is compact, which guarantees the discreteness of the spectrum of $L_{n}+V$.

Comment: But how do you see that exactly these boundary conditions make our operator self-adjoint. You explained the necessity of the boundary conditions very well, but how do I see that they do it?

Comment: One way you know this is very classical: The spherical harmonics form a complete orthonormal basis, and they satisfy the stated conditions. So you have an operator with a complete orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions; that operator must be selfadjoint. Another way is to know that the Laplacian on $C^{2}_{S}$ is essentially selfadjoint, meaning that its closure is selfadjoint. Another way to know this is that the Friedrichs extension for semibounded symmetric operator always gives a selfadjoint operator. And what I have described is the Friedrichs extension.

Comment: The key is first understanding the Laplacian. That's why I discussed that part at length. Then you look at the form domain after adding $V$.

Comment: Easiest way: Because your $V$ is bounded, then adding $V$ to $-\Delta$ is a bounded perturbation of a selfadjoint operator.

Comment: Let $-\Delta_{0}$ be the Laplacian on domain $C^{2}(S)$. Then the restriction of $-\Delta_{0}^{\star}$ to $\mathcal{D}((-\Delta_{0})^{\star})\cap (\mbox{Form Domain})$ is selfadjoint. In fact, as I mentioned, that restriction is the closure of $-\Delta_{0}$. There's a unique selfadjoint extension of $-\Delta_{0}$. Its domain can also be described in terms of eigenfunction expansions where $\sum_{\lambda}|\lambda_{n,m}|^{2}|c_{n,m}|^{2} < \infty$. These are equivalent. And, the perturbed operator obtained by adding a real function (+V) is selfadjoint on exactly the same domain.

Comment: @Tobias Hurth: Have a look at *Spectral Theory of Linear Differential Operators and Comparison Algebras* by H. O. Cordes. Corollary 1.7 pg 109. "For a complete Riemannian Manifold without boundary, all powers of the Laplace operator have their minimal operator essentially selfadjoint." The minimal operator is defined on $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$. That's the result that you want: the closure of the minimal operator is already selfadjoint. No conditions are needed there. This monograph of the London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series deals with a lot of advanced topics on manifolds.

Comment: @TobiasHurth: Okay, so I have now given you a reference for the Laplacian on the manifold without boundary. And I have added substantial detail at the bottom to get you going on how to relate the domain to Teschl's.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : I had forgotten ... the reference I gave you ... it starts with abstract boundary conditions, selfadjoint extensions of symmetric operators, Friedrichs extensions, form domains, a proof of the spectral theory, a version of the same for Sturm-Liouville operators of all orders, compactness of resolvents for Friedrichs extensions, and all of that in the first 100 pages. Get this one for your library. It's a horrible read, but it's packed full of stuff you can't find anywhere else.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : I doubt it. Legendre expansions arose originally from Legendre's power series expansion of Newtonian potential in spherical coordinates: $1/(1-2r\cos\theta+r^{2})^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_{n}(\cos\theta)r^{n}$. The Associated Legendre polynomials are derived from the same expansion of $1/(1-2r\cos\theta+r^{2})^{1/2+m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_{m,n}(\cos\theta)r^{n}$. The $P_{m,n}$ are solutions of the associated Legendre equation obtained when you differentiate Legendre's equation $m$ times, which you can just about see from how the series are related.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : When I said to differentiate the equation, I meant to replace $\cos\theta$ by $x$ and then differentiate $1/(1-2rx+r^{2})^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_{n}(x)r^{n}$ $m$ times with respect to $x$.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : You can't really tell. However, there are lowering operators for the unperturbed case. That kind of structure probably persists in some abstract form for problems of this type, but that's just a guess. That's where your intuition has to be much better than mine.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : I thought that the only hindrance to selfadjointness was that log function, which comes from the $n=0$ case, but I didn't want to say that unless I checked. You verified that by confirming the equation to be in the limit point case at the endpoints for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : I was thinking out loud about the fact that $n \ge 0$ gives you essentially selfadjoint equations, which is definitely different than for $n=0$, a case I analyzed here in this forum using asymptotics. Your question about discrete spectrum is not affected by that issue. For the $n \ne 0$ cases, you may be able to show that the $n^{2}/\sin^{2}\theta$ term is strong enough to force discrete spectrum (bound states.) If that is the case, then a perturbation by a nice $V$ is not going to change that property. Have you looked at that approach? There are standard results of that type.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : Do you know a theorem about how $-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+W$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$ has discrete spectrum if $W$ tends to $\infty$ in a prescribed way as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$? Such a thing exists, and I thought you might know it off the top of your head. It's intuitive for Physics. There aren't many conditions for this to be true.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : Because the associated ODEs where $n\ne 0$ have $n^{2}/\sin^{2}\theta)$ as an added potential term, and $V$ is not going to perturb that behavior. So that may give you discrete spectrum for $n\ne 0$ for the perturbed ODEs in $\theta$. That would pretty much give you what you want. Only the $n=0$ case would remain, where everything is limit circle.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : Yes, we can because we'll get a complete orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions for $-\Delta+V$ that are in the domain of $-\Delta +V$.

Comment: Once you know you have complete orthonormal bases $e_{n,1},e_{n,2},\cdots$ on $L^{2}_{\sin}[0,\pi]$ for each fixed $n$, then $\{ e^{inx}e_{n,m}, e^{-inx}e_{n,m}\}_{n,m}$ will be complete. You can show that by demonstrating Parseval's equality for the set.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : That's where you want to invoke a theorem about potentials tending to $\infty$ to get discrete spectrum. The potential for $n\ne 0$ is $\frac{n^{2}}{\sin^{2}\theta}+V(\theta)$. The problem is how these theorems work for this case on a finite interval. $n^{2}/\sin^{2}\theta+V(\theta)$ definite tends to $+\infty$ as $\theta\rightarrow 0,\pi$.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : I'm looking in Coddington and Levinson. They have a nice development of Sturm-Liouville, and they may have the result for the unbounded potential. We'll probably have to change variables to put the ODES into a more standard form without a weight factor. Looking ...

Comment: @TobiasHurth : I think I was making this too hard. Compactness arguments seem to work. Check what I added at the end. You need to know that $\|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\|\le 1/|\Im\lambda|$ for all $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$ whenever $A$ is selfadjoint. And you need to know that multiplication by $V$ has operator norm on $L^{2}_{\sin}[0,\pi]$ bounded by $\|V\|_{\infty}$.